# Remove draggable functionality when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjsfiddlenetuser/zyUkd/35/ I'm attempting to remove the draggable functionality of all divs that are styled with .myDivs when the button 'Remove Draggable' is clicked.

The function call     `$('.myDivs').draggable('disable');`  does not seem to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your `click` handler is made out of a `$(document).ready()` function, which means that it can be attached even if the DOM isn't totally loaded. Then, you didn't make the elements draggable with `draggable` but with `sortable`, so you should use `$(elements).sortable('disable')`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var els = $('.connected');
    els.sortable({
        connectWith : ".connected",
        items       : ".myDivs:not(.excludeThisCss)"
    }).disableSelection();

    $("#button").click(get);

    function get() {
        els.sortable('disable'); 
    }
});
```

Your updated JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zyUkd/38/

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that

```
$("#button").click(get);
```

is not in right place it must be inside onload event handler. So your code must look like this:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".connected" ).sortable({
        connectWith : ".connected",
        items       : ".myDivs:not(.excludeThisCss)"
    }).disableSelection();

    $("#button").click(get);
});


 function get() {
    $('.myDivs').draggable('disable'); 
}
```

Comment: The line: `$('.myDivs').draggable('disable');` is also a problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $( ".connected" ).sortable({
        connectWith : ".connected",        
        items       : ".myDivs:not(.excludeThisCss)"
    }).disableSelection();

   $("#button").click(function(){
   $( ".connected" ).sortable( "option", "disabled", true );
    });

});
```